# Get min values between hours for each day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas time series dataframe with a value for each hour of the day over an extended period, like this:

```
                     value
datetime                  
2018-01-01 00:00:00     38
2018-01-01 01:00:00     31
2018-01-01 02:00:00     78
2018-01-01 03:00:00     82
2018-01-01 04:00:00     83
2018-01-01 05:00:00     95
...
```

I want to create a new dataframe with the minimum value between hours 01:00 - 04:00 for each day but can't figure out how to do this.. the closest i can think of is:

```
df2 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='d'), df.between_time('01:00', '04:00')]).min()))
```

but that gives me:

> ValueError: Grouper for '' not 1-dimensional

Comment: Index first, ask questions later. (Index before you find the min, not in the groupby)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) with [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df = df.between_time('01:00', '04:00').resample('d').min()
print (df)
            value
datetime         
2018-01-01     31
```

Your solution is very close, only chain functions differently:

```
df = df.between_time('01:00', '04:00').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d')).min()
print (df)
            value
datetime         
2018-01-01     31
```